# how to append a xml data and add xml version and encoding in hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, hdfs

I have a hive query which extracts xml data as single entry from large set of xml data in hdfs.

```
<data>
    <book id="101">
        <sales>
          <date>12-20-2018</date>
          <quantity>25</quantity>
          <inventory>306</inventory>
        </sales>
    </book>
    <book id="102">
        <sales>
        </sales>
    </book>
    <book id="102">
        <sales>
        </sales>
    </book>
</data>
```

The current query separates the xml data into multiple rows of . Is there an efficient way to extract only data inside `<sales>..</sales>` tag and add xml version plus encoding (`xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"`). This data is to be stored in separate hive table.

Comment: can you share the DDL of the table, has it stored as xmlserde or stored just as string?

Comment: Gaurav, the xml data is stored as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `xml_data` is the table with the extracted `<book></book>` xml data and `book_data` is the column name. The query below does exactly as expected:

```
--check if sales tag exists in book_data 
--get everything inside sales tag and append 
 select 
 case when instr(book_data,'sales') > 0 
  then concat('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sales>',
                regexp_extract(book_data, '<sales>(.+?)</sales>'),'</sales>') 
 else null end as book_data from xml_data;
```